# Searching by SKU doesnt work

Tags: magento2, search, sku

I work on the Magento CE 2.0.7 and now I have a problem with the quicksearch.

My SKU'S like 00.00.00 and i have set ***SKU attribute is searchable*** in the backend. 
In the DB table ***'catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1'*** you can find the entries for the SKUs.

There is no mods belong searching installed.

I searched by '01.00.00' or 01.00.00, returns no search results.

Could you help me or some ideas?

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? What's the search term you enter? What happens? What should happen?

Comment: I searched by '01.00.00' or 01.00.00, returns no search results.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have solved your issue , from the version of M2 your are referring. Although I'm posting this solution, in case someone did not find a solution yet.

I had similar problem and found out that in `bin/magento indexer:status` I had on `Schedule Status` a message `suspended (101028 in backlog)`.

To solve my issue I reseted the indexer and reindexed again.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
```

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```